# Syntax error "Missing keyword" in case statement in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having some syntax error in my case statement where I am checking below condition:

```
((RAP10B.CLMSRC = '2', RAP01.EFFDT - 3 years <= RAP10.LOSSDT < RAP01.EFFDT) 
       OR 
(RAP10B.CLMSRC <> '2', RAP01.EFFDT - 3 years <= RAP10.LOSSDT < RAP01.EFFDT - 60 days)
```

Below is the code what I am using.

```
CASE
  WHEN RAP10B.CLMSRC = '2'
  THEN rap10.lossdt_t BETWEEN Add_months(rap01.teffdt_t, - 36) AND rap01.teffdt_t
  WHEN RAP10B.CLMSRC <> '2'
  THEN rap10.lossdt_t BETWEEN Add_months(rap01.teffdt_t, - 36) AND (rap01.teffdt_t - 60)
END
```

The error message is  "ORA-00905: missing keyword". But I am not able to find the missing thing.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is this case _expression_ in the WHERE clause?

Comment: @jarlh    I am using this case in where clasue, I have to use the condition which I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Don't do that. Use AND/OR constructions instead!

Answer (score 1):

It's generally much better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions in the `WHERE` clause instead of `case` *expressions*:

```
WHERE (RAP10B.CLMSRC = '2'
       AND rap10.lossdt_t BETWEEN Add_months(rap01.teffdt_t, - 36) AND rap01.teffdt_t)
   OR (RAP10B.CLMSRC <> '2'
       AND rap10.lossdt_t BETWEEN Add_months(rap01.teffdt_t, - 36) AND (rap01.teffdt_t - 60))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
CASE
   WHEN RAP10B.CLMSRC = '2'
      AND rap10.lossdt_t BETWEEN Add_months(rap01.teffdt_t, - 36) 
      AND rap01.teffdt_t THEN <your_column>
   WHEN RAP10B.CLMSRC <> '2'
      AND rap10.lossdt_t BETWEEN Add_months(rap01.teffdt_t, - 36) 
      AND (rap01.teffdt_t - 60) THEN <your_column>
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below -

```
CASE
  WHEN RAP10B.CLMSRC = '2'
  and rap10.lossdt_t BETWEEN Add_months(rap01.teffdt_t, - 36) AND rap01.teffdt_t then yourval
  WHEN RAP10B.CLMSRC <> '2'
  and rap10.lossdt_t BETWEEN Add_months(rap01.teffdt_t, - 36) AND (rap01.teffdt_t - 60) yourval1
END
```